# apt package precedence

Tags: apt, package-management

I have the following scenario: I want to install an apt package in the latest version on multiple machines. The repositories don't have the newest version, so I have just compiled the program from source and built a `.deb` file myself. Now I just named the package the same as in the official repositories. Will this lead to problems in the future? How does apt resolve conflicts, if there are two or more packages with the same name?

Comment: If your package is newer, then use a slightly higher version (like replacing `Foo-1.1.2` with `Foo-1.1.2~local_build`). Apt will automatically choose the higher version.

Comment: It can, I recall vividly the first package I named & gave it a version that I knew would get installed to replace the default package (*as intended*), alas if installed on a system my naming prevented future security fixes etc to be installed because official replacements would never exceed my chosen version, so name & versions do matter. I realized my mistake within the hour, but you've provided too few specifics for us to know what consequences you may have laid for yourself (*nor do we know the package name, thus how severe it could be etc; problems maybe only come release-upgrade time*)